# Packing characters into bits?

Tags: java, character, bit, packing

I am trying to pack characters into bits in terms of 0's and 1's. 
I have looked up many websites about bit-packing but I did not get any of them.

I just want a simple idea about bit-packing, and how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to know how to do it or know how it is done?  I suggest you just use DefaltorOutputStream or something like it to compress it.

Comment: I want to know how to do it. If you have some useful links that may help, I'd appreciate that!. Cheers

Comment: Define 'packing'. Characters are already sets of bits. Do you mean 'compres'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common compression algorithim which has been around a long time is [LZW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch) compression.

It is used by GZIP, PKZIP and JAR to name but a few and is suitable for compressing text.  It uses a combination of [Huffman encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding), [arithmetic coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding) and a few heuristics to make it more efficient.

> simple idea about bit-packing

If you find compression and bit packing in general simple, you are a rare breed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it can help you

```
public String StringtoBinary(String s) {

    char[] cArray=s.toCharArray();

    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

    for(char c:cArray)
    {
        String cBinaryString=Integer.toBinaryString((int)c);
        sb.append(cBinaryString);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Note: this example has a few problems a) it generates a string much larger b) it cannot be decoded c) it produces text from text.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should find out what compression algorithm you want to use. I recommend reading Huffman compression algorithm. What language are you using BTW ?